# Spresense LTE拡張ボードで接続までに時間がかかる場合がある

Tags: spresense

arduino IDEで開発です。スケッチ例のLteScanNetworks.inoで確認しています。
早いときは10秒程度で接続されattach succeededがでますが、
長いと20分以上接続されません。
SIMはtruphoneを使用しています。ドコモの４Gスマホの電波は良好です。
国内のSIMを使えば接続が早くなる可能性はあるでしょうか。
接続を早くする手続きはありますか。
拡張ボードのLTE LEDは不規則に点滅しています。
Signal Strengthは -90 前後です。
lteAccess.beginで2秒ちょっと
lteAccess.attachで7秒から場合によって20分以上かかっています。
接続が不安定な場合、timeoutする方法はあるでしょうか。

初めての接続ではない。
電源供給は確認した。

よろしくお願いします。

追記
もしかしたら、この状況でしょうか。
https://www.soracom.io/blog/sim-activation-cellular-modem-fix/
何らかの原因でネットワークの情報のキャッシュがクリアされたとき、遅くなる？
対策方法がいくつか出ていますが、arduinoIDEからどのように設定するのでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

こんにちは。

私はSoracomさんのSIMを使っておりますが、たいていの場合10秒くらい(長くても1分程度)でLTEにAttachできております。

動作確認SIMに入っているSIMを使うと接続が早くなるかもしれません。
[LTE-M 動作確認SIM List](https://developer.sony.com/ja/develop/spresense/specifications/spresense-lte-sim-list)

追記

> 接続が不安定な場合、timeoutする方法はあるでしょうか。

`lteAccess.attach()` 関数は、一番最後の引数に同期/非同期のふるまいを選択できるようになっているので、これを`false`にすると途中で中断するプログラムを作成できると思います。
`LteGnssTracker.ino` サンプルが非同期のふるまいを使った方法を使っているので、参考になるかもしれません。

Comment: spresenseの英語のページや村田製作所でもtruphoneが紹介されていたのでいけるかもとチャレンジしました。つながれば問題なく通信出来ているのでなんとかならないかと試行錯誤してみます。情報ありましたら引き続きよろしくお願いします。

Comment: 5jinさんも記載されているように、TruphoneのSIMはローミングを使っているので、動作確認SIMよりは時間がかかってしまうのは仕方ないと思います。

Comment: 参考になりました。ありがとうございます。非同期で`lteAccess.getStatus()`を監視して原因と対策を検討します。